# Excel, Countif character limit, Replace with Sumifs Or SumProduct?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following formula that won't work with more than a character limit of 255.

`=COUNTIF(Nodes!B:B,Sheet1!D4&"/*")`

I tried

`=SUMIFS(Nodes!F:F, Nodes!B:B, Sheet1!D4&"/*")`

And would like to try `sumproduct` to achieve this formula where characters is greater than 255.

Trying something like `=SUMPRODUCT(--(Nodes!B:B:Nodes!F:F=$D4&"/*"))` or
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(Nodes!B:B=sheet1!D4&"/*"))`

But I am getting a value of `0` when it shouldn't be this.

Comment: I believe that you will run into this character length issue with any Excel formula.  While I could be overlooking some formula solution, I would suggest posting this to StackOverflow for a VBA solution.

Comment: sigh , i thought some people use `sumproduct` t overcome the limitations of `countif`

Comment: Try `=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D4&"/*",Nodes!B:B:Nodes!F:F))))`  Not sure if it will work or not.

Comment: @excelguy, could you just write what exactly you are trying to Count or  share sample data with us. !!

Comment: @excelguy, meanwhile you can this way,, `=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D4&"/*",Nodes!B:B)))*(Nodes!F:F))`

Answer (score 0):

Array formulas and formulas using arrays in one form or another (`VLOOKUP`, `COUNTIF`, etc...) don't accept strings longer than 255 characters. One way to work around it in your case is with some helper columns:

1) Split the text into multiple columns using Data -> Text to Columns, using the "Fixed Width" option. To minimize the number of columns, use 255 characters.

Use `COUNTIFS` to count the nodes:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!B1,Sheet2!C:C,Sheet1!C1,Sheet2!D:D,Sheet1!D1)
```

checking as many columns as required.

Comment: Clever, but how to find matches when the first part of the string is in column `C` and the second part is in column `D`?  Also, the formulas are popping an error on the criteria being too long, not the cell contents.

Comment: In answer to you first question, if you split the text in an orderly fashion, it will not happen. In answer to your second question, the criteria is too long because the strings used as criteria are too long and those strings are the cell contents. By limiting the length of cell contents, you limit the string length and thus the criteria